# At it's core, how is boost tuple implemented (without all the extra details in the boost header)

Tags: c++, templates, boost

It seems to be a hardcoded template with 10 things, but there is also an implementation for a cons template class very similar to Typelist from Lokki. So is the boost tuple template just a wrapper around a Typelist/cons implementation? Or what is the gist of it?

Comment: I am sure you have already gone through this but nonetheless: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tuple/doc/design_decisions_rationale.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++03 (because otherwise we would be talking about `std::tuple`) there is no variadic template feature, therefore it is emulated with a sufficient number of parameters (*) with a specific default.

You can get a hint of the actual implementation reading the [Design decisions rationale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tuple/doc/design_decisions_rationale.html):

> **The end mark of the cons list (nil, null_type, ...)**
>
> Tuples are internally represented as cons lists:
>
> ```
> tuple<int, int>
> ```
>
> inherits from
>
> ```
> cons<int, cons<int, null_type> >
> ```
>
> `null_type` is the end mark of the list. Original proposition was `nil`,
>   but the name is used in MacOS, and might have caused problems, so
>   `null_type` was chosen instead. Other names considered were `null_t` and
>   `unit` (the empty tuple type in SML).
>
> Note that `null_type` is the internal representation of an empty tuple:
>   `tuple<>` inherits from `null_type`.

(*) Usually in Boost the code is generated with the use of macros so that the upper limit is configurable.